# FOTS - Foreign units disappeared when realm divide

Tags: shogun-2-total-war

Was playing a Fall of the Samurai dominion campaign (normal difficulty clan with very hard difficulty combats). I rushed to foreign units and bought only Imperial infantry, Imperial guard infantry and Colonial infantry (not sure the name for the last, the one you get by having a british port).

When the "Realm divided" came, I chose to stand alone against the rest of Japan, just to try to survive (already finished a game fighting for the Shogun). But instantly all my units except agents and generals just... disappeared... I went instantly from 12k gold per turn to 32k just because I lost so much of my fees.

Tried to Google my problem but cannot find a single other player facing my problem. Is this a know bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it ! When the "Realm divide" comes in FOTS, choosing to stand alone does remove all "Shogunate" and "Imperial" units. It is specified when you have to make your choice (but who reads the details on the choice screen...). I made an additional test and indeed, the Colonial elite infantry units did not disappear, only Imperial and Imperial Guard.

Btw, I'm wondering if it is possible to stand alone... all your cities suddenly have the "mounting unrest" event because you have a 100% shogunate or imperial population... but you are not shogunate or imperial anymore...